# Rolling Average Report for Closed Deals By User in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

I am trying to create a Rolling Average Report in Salesforce to show the Rolling Average of Deals Closed by each User.

Example Of Rolling Average :

**USER 1**

JAN - Average of Jan Closed Deals

FEB - Average of JAN + FEB Closed Deals

MARCH - Average of JAN + FEB + MARCH Closed Deals

---

DEC - Average of JAN + FEB + MARCH+ --till-- + DEC Closed Deals

**USER 2**

JAN - Average of Jan Closed Deals

FEB - Average of JAN + FEB Closed Deals

MARCH - Average of JAN + FEB + MARCH Closed Deals

---

DEC - Average of JAN + FEB + MARCH+ --till-- + DEC Closed Deals

Using below formula I am able to get the Sum but not the average, is there any option to get this with Salesforce Report?

```
PARENTGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 1),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 2),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 3),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 4),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 5),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 6),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 7),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 8),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 9),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 10),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, CLOSE_DATE, 11),0)
```